# "Early in something" vs. "early on something"

Tags: difference, word-difference

It seems that both expressions are used for "early in the process". Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

Not really.

You might say *early in something*, and you might also say, *early on in something*, but that's not quite the same as *early on something*.

For example, I might say:

> Things are going well so far, but we're still fairly **early in the process**.

I might also say:

> Things are going well so far, but we're still fairly **early on in the process**.

But I would probably NOT say:

> Things are going well so far, but it's still pretty <strike>early on the process</strike>.

NOAD defines **early on** as a phrasal verb meaning:

> **early (or earlier) on**
>   at an early (or earlier) stage in a particular time or period: *they discovered early on that the published data were wrong*.

Notice that the sample sentence doesn't have an object.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/early+on) adds this usage note:

> #### Usage Discussion of *early on*
>
> This adverb is sometimes objected to in American writing as an obtrusive Briticism. It is a relative newcomer to the language, having arisen in British English around 1928. It seems to have filled a need, however. It came into frequent use in American English in the late 1960s and is now well established on both sides of the Atlantic in both speech and writing.

Most of the time, when it's followed by an "in the something," you can probably leave the *on* part out:

> The farmer milks his cows early in the day.
>   The farmer milks his cows early on in the day.

Those two roughly mean the same thing, although keeping the *on* in the sentence does may suggest that the milking of the cows is just one smaller segment of a very busy morning.

Likewise, the M-W example sentence could be rewritten as:

> They discovered early *in their experiments* that the published data were wrong.

Comment: So, you basically say that "on" particle can be omitted, if I get it right.